# Configure Proguard-rules with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-proguard

I've this project and i use Firebase Realtime Database.

[image]

It's correct write this proguard rules?

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class activity.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class adapter.** {
   *;
}
-keepclassmembers class fragment.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class persistence.** {
  *;
}
-keepclassmembers class services.** {
   *;
}
```

The app work perfectly but when i release on PlayStore it seem that the query doesn't work. In my gradle i added

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `-keep` for classes that will be serialized/deserialized by firebase, otherwise it won't be able to use reflection on those classes. `-keepclassmembers` will only keep the members and obfuscate the name of the class, which is something you definitely don't want to do if your libs use reflection. Try replacing `-keepclassmembers` with `-keep` for those classes.

```
-keep class persistence.** {
  *;
}
```

Comment: Ok! Now it seems that work...but the code for authentication the phone (by Firebase auth) not arrive

Comment: What do you mean by not arrive?

Comment: When you authenticate with Firebase, a verification code should arrive

Comment: This might no be related to proguard at all, did you check if you're not receiving an error? Also, if you've authenticated recently you won't receive a new code

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class persistence.**  {
*;
}
```

Here the `**` represents that each and every file is included in the following package.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add any information that's not covered by this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292444).