# Wrong tree names inserted with Firebase Insert Operation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I'm trying to insert some users data into Firebase database, and I have successfully inserted some records. However, I have a minor problem that on some android devices insert operation is not working fine and creates trees/nodes for user's data named a,b,c instead of custom keys.**

I have already implemented all the helper and interfaces to insert data into Firebase.

I have added User Model class which I'm using to insert data.

```
public class User {
    public String uid;
    public String email;
    public String userRole;
    public String firebaseToken;

    public User(){

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getFirebaseToken() {
        return firebaseToken;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setFirebaseToken(String firebaseToken) {
        this.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
    public User(String uid,String email,String userRole,String firebaseToken)
    {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
        this.email = email;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
}

User user = new User(firebaseUser.getUid(),
                firebaseUser.getEmail(),
                userRole,
                new SharedPrefUtil(context).getString(Constants.ARG_FIREBASE_TOKEN));
        database.child(Constants.ARG_USERS)
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                .setValue(user)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mOnUserDatabaseListener.onSuccess("User Added Successfully");
                        } else {
                            mOnUserDatabaseListener.onFailure("Unable To Add User");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Most likely you've shipped an APK where proguard ran on some of your data classes to those users. Make sure you've disabled proguard on any POJO classes that you read from/write to the database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292125/configure-proguard-rules-with-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the information.
I will try to regenerate the apk with desired pro-guard rules.
Definitely an upwote if it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use `@PropertyName` annotation. That marks a field to be renamed when serialized.

Comment: i'm facing this problem on some of android devices.

Comment: Yeah, Maybe that use of annotation will solve your issue. all you need to do is just use this annotation on the property and give the name.

Comment: where to use this annotation

Comment: You have to use that annotation on the getter & setter of properties in POJO class, Make your property as `Private` and give the annotation on the getter & setter
like below. 
`@PropertyName("tree-name")`.